# Good way to discriminate between Mathematica/PlayerPro/CDFPlayer

Tags: compatibility, wolfram-player

Within a Mathematica program with a graphical user interface I want to programmatically determine whether the code runs in a full Mathematica, a Player Pro or a CDF-Player. There seem to not be any documented functions which would allow to get that information. I understand that this might be on purpose, as the idea is that it shouldn't matter. At least Mathematica Player Pro provides basically the same functionality as Mathematica. But there are some subtle differences and of course the CDFPlayer has well known limitations.

For the moment I have ways to get that information, but they are all somewhat dirty and/or not very reliable:

- Look at variables like `$InstallationDirectory` or `$BaseDirectory` and check for known 
  directory names
- Look at `SystemInformation[]` or `Options[$FrontEnd]` and use heuristics to get the 
  desired information from what these return.
- try something that is known to not work with CDF Player (e.g. export data). Will of 
  course not work for a Player Pro.

and of course one could use any combination of these things to get a more reliable result.

Does anyone know a better way to get that information?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [**official comparison**](http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I think it is about getting info on the environment the code is running in (i.e. Mathematica, Player etc.)

Comment: Perhaps try `$LicenseType` (`"Professional"` for *Mathematica*; presumably something else for Player) or the supposedly (but not really) deprecated `$ProductInformation` (gives `"ProductIDName" -> "Mathematica"` vs. `"ProductIDName" -> "MathematicaPlayer"`). For the CDF plugin you can check `CurrentValue[PluginEnabled]`.

Comment: Oh, and if you want to figure out if you're running in the plugin/Player sandbox, you can use ``Developer`$ProtectedMode`` for that too.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @Ajasja because all of this is undocumented and I don't have the Player installed or the time to test it properly. Whoever does and can state definitively what the results will be in various situations and for different versions of the relevant products is welcome to use my suggestions in their own answer if they wish.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: your comments seem to have triggered the answer that I accepted, so thanks a lot for these...

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: no, I knew that comparison. What I looked for was what Yves mentioned. Oleksandrs comments are exactly what I was looking for...

Comment: @AlbertRetey you're welcome! Glad that others were able to add the missing details to answer your question properly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The straightforward way to discriminate is to use `$LicenseType`, (unfortunately undocumented and not even `WolframLanguageData` knows about it). Deploying the following line as a CDF file and opening it in various environments provides the following results (thanks for [Oleksandr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r)'s comment):

```
Dynamic@{$LicenseType, Developer`$ProtectedMode, CurrentValue["PluginEnabled"]}

(* Mathematica 8-10 *)           {"Professional", False, False}
(* CDF Player *)                 {"Player", False, False}
(* Firefox w/ browser plugin *)  {"Professional", True, True}
(* Player Pro *)                 {"Player Pro", False, False}
```

For more on `$LicenseType`, see [other thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117894/what-does-licensetype-return-on-various-wolfram-language-desktop-evaluation-pla).

---

As of version 10, one can also use [`$EvaluationEnvironment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$EvaluationEnvironment.html), answering a different, but related question. It returns one of the followings:

```
"Session"          local interactive session
"RemoteSession"    remote interactive session
"CDF"              standalone CDF
"Script"           script run in batch mode
"Subkernel"        parallel or grid subkernel
"WebEvaluation"    direct URL evaluation
"WebLoad"          evaluation when loading a webpage
"WebAPI"           API called through an HTTP request
"WebForm"          web form
"WebServer"        web server plugin (e.g. JSP)
"CloudCDF"         cloud CDF
"PlugInCDF"        CDF web plugin
"Scheduled"        scheduled task
"WolframLink"      WolframLink call
```

Please feel free to add to the lists if you know other licenses/environments.

Comment: Thanks for helping to flesh this out into a useful answer. Another thing I had been wondering is what `$LicenseType` is for *Mathematica* for Students or the Home Edition? I don't have either of these products so I can't easily check, but perhaps someone else can fill in the additional details?

Comment: Great stuff here, I should browse your answer more carefully :P

Comment: Thanks @Kuba; in this case I've just found out about `$EvaluationEnvironment` while browsing the non-final documentation online. Many things are revealed from weak to weak as they are getting closer to roll out the new version.

Comment: I  still think that your answer correctly answers my question, but in the current form it isn't very clear as the description of `$EvaluationEnvironment` is too prominent (IMO), considering in the "final" implementation seems to be a solution to a different while related problem. I would consider the use of `$LicenseType` is the answer to my question as it was stated. As `$EvaluationEnvironment` is of course also interesting, I wouldn't want that to be removed, but I'd suggest to probably make more clear that it actually is `$LicenseType` which answers the question.

Comment: @Albert Done. I'm quite disappointed that I couldn't figure out more about `$LicenseType` though. Perhaps someone else.

Comment: well, it ist (still undocumented, just as the fronend-value "$NotebookLicenseType"). So whatever we use here, it is either heuristics or undocumented...

Comment: One more thing, I'm not sure but would expect that the outcome of $LicenseType within the plugin depends on whether the plugin runs a player or full mathematica version. You probably have seen my other question which asks for as many return values as possible so maybe we might know more in a few days. And yes, thanks for making those changes!

Comment: @Albert No, I haven't seen, but now I've linked it from my answer as I think it is a very useful question!

Answer (score 10):

The following

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd@FrontEnd`Value["$NotebookLicenseType"]
```

will distinguish "Player Pro" from just "Player", or *Mathematica*, which the other methods do not handle if you need to make such a distinction.

Comment: In Wolfram CDF Player Version 10 this gives "Professional".

Answer (score 5):

These are undocumented, but I doubt they will change much going forward...  I think they are available in v9 or later, but I don't recall exactly when they were introduced...

```
FE`Evaluate@FEPrivate`PlayerQ[]
FE`Evaluate@FEPrivate`PlayerProQ[]
```

`` FEPrivate`PlayerQ[] `` returns True when the document is running in CDF Player mode.  `` FEPrivate`PlayerProQ[] `` returns True when the document is an EnterpriseCDF or is running inside of an activated copy of CDF Player.

If you use them inside of a `Dynamic`, you probably would not need to use the `` FE`Evaluate `` wrapper.

Comment: thanks, great finding. As none of the other solutions are documented I think this is just as good as any of them. I'll try to experiment with that to learn whether it fits my purposes as good or better than the other possibilities...