# Detect Standalone CDF vs Browser Plugin environment

Tags: cdf-format, deployment, system, enterprise-cdf

Recently, Wolfram informed me that there's no way to have a Print button in a CDF running within a plugin environment since the plugin does not interact with the operating system.
If you have a way to solve that, it would be great!

But now more importantly, since there are such significant differences between the 2 environments, including the security sandbox, is there any way to detect programmaticly in which environment the CDF is being displayed, so that one could adjust what is being displayed to the user, and what is not?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14193/5

Comment: @rm-rf: you're right, it is. Didn't find it when I search for this info prior to posting. THANK YOU! There's a very thorough answer contained there.

Comment: @GregoryKlopper You're welcome :) I'll mark this as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is how to determine if the file is being viewed in the plug-in, then here's how:

```
CurrentValue["PluginEnabled"]
```

Comment: This is a good enough answer to get awarded an "answer", but as I recently found out, the full answer is a combination of a few things `Dynamic@{$LicenseType, Developer`$ProtectedMode, CurrentValue["PluginEnabled"]}`