# How to identify the program that is running my notebook or CDF file

Tags: programming, gui-construction

Is there a way to programatically know which Wolfram product is evaluating a notebook or cdf file: Mathematica, CDF Player, or CDF Player Pro, Wolfram Cloud? I'm currently using $InstallationDirectory but I assume there should be a more reliable way to get this information.  The reason for the question is that currently DialogInput is not supported in CDF Player family of products, so identifying the product running a program helps generating a solution when DialogInput is needed.

Comment: `Options[$FrontEnd, Evaluator]` evaluates to `Evaluator -> "Local"` with Mathematica and to `{}` for Wolfram Cloud. However, this doesn't help for the CDF browser plug-in as you get the same output as with Mathematica. Hence, not very useful.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? [Good way to discriminate between Mathematica/PlayerPro/CDFPlayer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14193/5478)

Comment: Btw. `$EvaluationEnvironment` mostly fails to give a correct answer. Can anyone reproduce it?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks.  Should I trust $EvaluationEnvironment?  It seems like  $LicenseType returns what I need.

Comment: The documentation for `$EvaluationEnvironment` says that this function depends on access to the Wolfram Cloud.  Maybe `StringQ@CloudEvaluate[$EvaluationEnvironment]` is a good integrity test for the function.  Then, when there is no access to the cloud using `$InstallationDirectory` seems to be the best approach so far.