# How useful is $EvaluationEnvironment?

Tags: functions, bugs, evaluation

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.3**

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3618534] was created.
>
> [...]  I filed a report with our development team raising the issues [...]

---

`$EvaluationEnvironment` was supposed to be a panacea for: [Good way to discriminate between Mathematica/PlayerPro/CDFPlayer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14203/5478)

But from my experience it is not full working in a "desktop" area.

The remaining question is: I don't have time to check everything, could you? :)

#### Working:

- `"WebEvaluation"`
- `"WebAPI"`
- `"WebForm"`
- `"Subkernel"` (*fixed somewhere around 11.2*)

#### I'm not sure

- `"Session"` - it works well but all others that fail return "Session" so tough to count on it
- `"WebLoad"` not clear in comparison to `"WebAPI"`
- `"RemoteSession", "WebServer", "CloudCDF", "PlugInCDF", "WSTP"` - not tested

#### Not working:

- `"CDF"`
- `"Script"`
- `"Scheduled"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bug is confirmed and a workaround is available in the linked topic.

Nothing to do here now so I will move the `code` part of the question to this wiki answer to remove it from an unanswered stack and make a terse list on top.

#### Code samples to reproduce specific values of `$EvaluationEnvironment`:

- `"WebEvaluation"`

  ```
  CloudEvaluate[$EvaluationEnvironment]
  ```
- `"WebAPI"`

  ```
  CloudDeploy[
    APIFunction[{"x" -> String}, $EvaluationEnvironment &]
  ] //  URLExecute[#, {"x" -> "100"}, "JSON"] &
  ```
- `"WebForm"`

  ```
  CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"x" -> String}, $EvaluationEnvironment &]]
  ```
- `"Subkernel"`

  ```
  ParallelEvaluate[{$KernelID, $EvaluationEnvironment}, Kernels[]]
  ```

---

- `"WebLoad"`

  ```
  CloudDeploy@Delayed@{$EvaluationEnvironment, DateList[]}
  ```

---

- `"CDF"`

  ```
   SystemOpen @ CDFDeploy[
     "test.cdf"
   , Dynamic[{RandomReal[], $EvaluationEnvironment}, UpdateInterval -> 1]
   ]
  ```
- `"Script"`

  ```
  path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "test.wl"}];

  Export[path, "Print @ $EvaluationEnvironment", "Text"];

  Import["! math.exe -script " <> path , "Text"]
  ```
- `"Scheduled"`

  ```
   RunScheduledTask[Print@$EvaluationEnvironment, {2}]
  ```

Comment: As of 12.0 `RunScheduledTask[Print@$EvaluationEnvironment, {2}]` prints "Session"