# What does $LicenseType return on various Wolfram Language desktop evaluation platforms

Tags: compatibility, licensing, cdfplayer, wolfram-player

Referring to my [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14203/169) about discriminating between various variants of Mathematica, Wolfram Player etc. I was wondering what the values of

```
$LicenseType
```

and

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd@FrontEnd`Value["$NotebookLicenseType"]
```

in various systems and versions. What I know is that they are

```
{"Professional","Professional"}
```

for every (standard licensed) Mathematica version since at least version 7 on Windows and

```
{"Player Pro","Player Pro"}
```

on "Wolfram Player Pro" version 9 and "CDF Player Pro" version 10 (despite the name that is the same thing in different versions as far as I know).

for a free player I think the result will be (can't test that right now but have done that for several older versions):

```
{"Player","Player"}
```

What I'd be interested to know is what these would return for other variants, like e.g. the home/student/trial/free player etc. It would also be interesting to know what the various variants would return when run in a browser via the browser plugin (although that functionality nowadays seems to be considered "deprecated" as the main browsers plan to not support plugins anymore in the future).

Note: an interesting fact is that using the "File" -> "CDF Preview" will return `{"Player","Professional"}` for both the "CDF Player" and the "Player Pro" emulation, which most probably is an overview...

Comment: `{"Professional", "Enterprise"}` for V10.4.1 Enterprise Edition.